# How to make optgroups using ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I'm working with ASP.NET. I want to make optgroups in a DropDownList using data binding to data from SQL Server. For example, I've got 2 tables — one for country & another for states. In my drop down list in ASP.NET, I want to bind to the data in these 2 tables. The country table should become optgroup, & states should go under that.

```
-India-
  kerala
  tamilnadu
-america-
  newyork
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can solve this with a hack. Override RenderContents of the DropDownlist like this
http://weblogs.asp.net/jeff/archive/2006/12/27/dropdownlist-with-optgroup.aspx